# Nuclide React Native Inspector change port

Tags: react-native, nuclide-editor

I'm using Nuclide 0.178.0 and the **React Inspector**, but **It's listening on port 8097**.

I can't find **where to change that**. There is no mention of inspector in the settings.

Debugger is correctly set and work fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are running app on android try `adb reverse 8097 8097` from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the path "node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/server.js" ,change the default port "8081" to your port